# how to show taxonomy subcatgory in breadcrumb of drupal

Tags: drupal, breadcrumbs, drupal-taxonomy

I am using Taxonomy_Manager and Menu_breadcrumb modules
my categories looks like:
**+BUSINESS**
 ++Agriculture
 ++Banking & Finance
 ++Construction & Real Estate
**+News**
 ++ Behind the news
 ++ Peace and War

now the question is: if i browse any sub-category, it will not appear in the breadcrumb
(the breadcrumb will be "Home>>") while if i browse one of the main categories, it will appear normally in the breadcrumb ("Home>>News")
i have tried taxonomy_breadcrumb but this didnt fix the issue :(
how can i set the subcategories to appear in the breadcrumb??
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these modules:

1. http://drupal.org/project/hansel
2. http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my breadcrumb-taxonomy related problems overriding the druapal breadcrumb function. You have to go to your theme folder and add the follow function in your template.php file.

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_breadcrumb( $variables )
{
    // init
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

    // taxonomy hierarchy
    $hierarchy = array();
    if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) 
    {
        $tid = (int)arg(2);
        $parents = array_reverse(taxonomy_get_parents_all($tid));
        foreach( $parents as $k=>$v)
        {
            if( $v->tid==$tid ) continue;
            $breadcrumb[] = l($v->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $v->tid);;
        }
    }

    // rendering
    if (!empty($breadcrumb))
    {
        $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
        $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode("<span class='separator'>&raquo;</span>", $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```